# Add an appendix to sites

Tags: feature-request

I asked a question requesting a good ASCII table a few years ago on SO and it was closed, it has since been deleted and I don't think it's worth it to start a SE site for ASCII table enthusiasts (Maybe ASCII art enthusiasts would work).

Anyway, if there was an extremely limited appendix on SO that would be really helpful.  It might solve the 'General Reference' issue and make my life easier.  It could be written by the more prolific and pedantic tag wiki authors.

I only ask this because I can't find the ASCII table I usually use since I cleaned my desk two days ago.  But it's an idea, maybe a novel one.  I can't tell from the related questions, downvote accordingly ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you trying to replace bookmarks or google?

Comment: @Mat, Nope, I'm trying to replace the paper that I lost.

Comment: FWIW, the top-voted answer on [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898023/whats-the-nicest-ascii-table-youve-seen) (10k) has a broken image anyway :)

Comment: @balpha, yeah I never liked the one that was the top voted on there anyway.  It was just the first thing google found then.

Answer (score 4):

> It could be written by the more prolific and pedantic tag wiki authors.

A better idea might be to just have those "prolific and pedantic tag wiki authors" create tag wikis instead.
It certainly seems like this would work fine in the *majority* of cases where you'd want an appendix, without having to add any extra complexity to the site.

For example, there is already an [ascii](/questions/tagged/ascii) tag on Stack Overflow: add the ASCII table you want to see there. Remember that any registered user can suggest edits for a tag wiki. Just click ["improve description"](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/1843).

And for answers to questions that would otherwise be a good fit on the site (things you might be tempted close as "general reference"), the best thing to do would be to ask a well-written question about it (or find an *existing* well-written question about it), post a canonical answer, and relentlessly close all of questions as duplicates of that one. Combining the two ideas, you could even add a link to this question in a FAQ section of the relevant tag wiki(s).

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ascii/info